# How can I make a path for a folder on the root?

Tags: css, path, directory

Here is my directory:

```
/myweb
    /css
        style.css
    /img
        icon.png
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

I need to call `icon.png` in `style.css`. I've tested lots of cases but none of these works:

```
// style.css

url(../img/icon.png)
url(./img/icon.png)
url(/img/icon.png)
url(img/icon.png)
url(../icon.png)
url(./icon.png)
```

Does anybody know what's the correct path?

Comment: What url are you using to access myweb?

Comment: @Corporalis `http://localhost/myweb`

Comment: In which case you could use `url("../img/icon.png")`. The path would be relative to the stylesheet. Or of course you could use  `url("/myweb/img/icon.png")` which starts from the root, although I wouldn't recommend that as it might need to work in a different environment, but it's a worthwhile test. If that's not working, it would be worth seeing a bit more css.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `url(../img/icon.png)` is correct.
Did you try to call the image from somewhere else, in example for background:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/icon.png);
}
```

Also please check the configuration in your `.htaccess`.